# Getting only top 10 values from an Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-formula, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have created some pivot tables which shows sales of PC from different brands for multiple years. for example 2013 PC sales of dell,HP,Apple etc...

Now I want to compare these sales but I just want to compare top 10 results...I am trying to create a table which will show only the top ten values from the pivot table. I dont want to filter the pivot table to top 10 values.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Why don't you want to filter the pivot table? Is to possible to sort the values from largest to smallest?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create your output as a table without filtering the pivot table, you can use [cube functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/cube-functions-reference-HA010083026.aspx).  Create a cubeset that is all PC brands and order them by PC Sales.  Create cubrankedmember functions for positions 1 through 10.  Then write a cubevalue formula next to each cuberankedmember to retrieve the associated value. If you want to post a little more about your data model, I could write more specific cube function formulas.

Comment: I need a bit more guidance as i new to powerpivot...So here is what i am trying..I have created a kind of dash board where I can change some pivot tables and other normal table based on a drop down selection for example I selected HP then HP's data should come. Now I tried to create powerpivot table and converted it to formulas but that made the table static and I cannot use that static data ...

Comment: You are on the right track.  Converting the table to formulas created cube functions.  But those are hard coded.  That is why you need to use cubrankedmember and cubesets instead of using the cubemembers that you see when when you convert to formulas.  I would need to see a pivot table or your cube model to be able to help you further.